# Understanding the usage of the syntax "<DataType>" in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, templates

I want to understand the usage of the "`<DataType>`" in C++.
As far as I read about, it is the syntax used for templates, which uses the specified data type for specialization of function or class instantiation.

Coming from python, I understand that all data types are by definition a class (correct me if it does not apply for C++), so if you look for the int implementation in python, you will find:

```
class int: 
    @overload 
    def __new__(cls: Type[_T], x: str | bytes | SupportsInt | SupportsIndex | _SupportsTrunc = ...) -> _T: ...
 ...
```

Which constructor is overloaded based in arguments. So why in C++ it does not use (dataType) instead of `<dataType>` and overload the constructor based on the type of the arguments?

Also, can I safely state that every time `<DataType>` appears, it is surely a template there?

some examples:

```
std::vector<int> x;
std::vector< std::vector<int> >& someVar;

cv::Mat opencvMat;
int x = static_cast<int>(opencvMat.at<float>(i, 3) * frameWidth);
```

Comment: *Coming from python, i understand that all data types are by definition a class (correct me if it does not apply for c++)* That is not true for C or C++.  Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Why does one language do things differently then another language? Well because they are different languages. The vectors are class templates, static_cast and .at (from opencvMat) are template functions

Comment: If you are sure that `DataType` in `<DataType>` is a type and not a variable, I think it's pretty safe to say that it's a template. Otherwise it could be an expression. `a<foo>b` where `a<foo` produces a `bool` and there's an operator that lets you do `bool > decltype(b)`.

Comment: @P Kramer, i did not ask why it is different from python, i just gave one exemple to ask why not simply use overload (like in python or even c). Anyway, thanks for point out that my exemples are all templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use your examples:

```
std::vector<int> x;
```

`x` is a vector (dynamic-length array) that contains ints.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> >& someVar;
```

`someVar` is a reference to a vector of vectors. The inner vectors holds ints. This would be a common way to make a reference to a two-dimensional dynamic array, where each row could have a different number of columns.

```
int x = static_cast<int>(opencvMat.at<float>(i, 3) * frameWidth);
```

This is how you do various styles of cast. I'll break it into two:

```
opencvMat.at<float>(i, 3)
```

I don't use this library, but the at method is probably a template, and it means you're going to receive a float.

The static_cast forces the calculated value to an int without a compiler warning for loss of precision.

As you've figured out, this is all related to templates, and you'll see templates are defined using <>. For instance:

```
template <class ObjectType>
class Foo:
public:
     ObjectType value;
};

Foo<std::string> myFoo;
```

In this case, myFoo.value is a string.

Comment: note: OpenCV knows the element type of its Mat but that's not type-safe (encoded as an enum in the object). the `at<>()` method has to be given the C++ element type. if that type does *not* match what's actually stored in memory, you'll get garbage out.